# PNG image (in anchor) is not showing transparent background

Tags: image, anchor, transparency

Please look [here](https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/support-forums/). You can see a list of forums:

[image: Forum list]

I can;t work out why the image is not showing with a transparent background because the image itself does:

[image: Icon]

How do I resolve this? I saw similar questions that mentioned `background-color: transparent;` but I removed the styling as it didn't seem to work.

Comment: The image with its alpha removed has a _pure black_ background, and the image is smaller than that gray block, so the transparency certainly is working. You just need to check if there's some specific style for the background colour of that block it's in. Which, um, probably makes it a WordPress question rather than a StackOverflow one? I'm not sure why this was migrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this  issue out. I had to use this additional styling:

```css
#bbpress-forums .bsp_thumbnail img {
    max-width: 48px !important;
    max-height: 48px !important;

    min-width: 48px !important;
    min-height: 48px !important;

    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
    border:  none !important;
}
```